# Differences between versions 1.x and 2.x of the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: support, api, java

I had written a Java Wrapper for the Stack Exchange API, version 1.x, Which was working perfectly.
But, since 12 May 2014, services for version 1.x have been shutdown and my Wrapper stopped working.

Before I move forward to make changes to my Java wrapper to make it compatible with V2.x , I wanted to know what are the changes between V1.x Vs V2.x in terms of:

- Request URL and parameters
- JSON response format

Comment: Here the changelog: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/change-log

Comment: Earlier with version 1.x , parameters body=true comments=true and answers=true etc were available. but seems not supported with API version 2.x.  Are these params not supported in new API ? are these params moved to filters ?

Comment: @Sanjiv They've been moved to filters.

Answer (score 1):

The changes in version of the API are documented in the [Change log](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/change-log).

For V2.0 it has the following info on the request URL:

- All API request now go to api.stackexchange.com with a site parameter
- Every method of the form /users/{ids}* now has a /me version, which is the same as calling the /users/{ids} version with the user id of the passed access_token passed

And for the response format:

- All method now return a common response wrapper object, which places data in the items property.

That wrapper object is described [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper):

| field | type | Descripton |
| --- | --- | --- |
| backoff | integer | may be absent |
| error_id | integer | refers to an error may be absent |
| error_message | string | may be absent |
| error_name | string | may be absent |
| has_more | boolean |  |
| items | an array of the type found in type |  |
| page | integer |  |
| page_size | integer |  |
| quota_max | integer |  |
| quota_remaining | integer |  |
| total | integer |  |
| type | string |  |